# disabled canvas has different shape than enabled

Tags: apache-flex, canvas, cornerradius

I have a simple canvas:

```
<mx:Canvas
    id="can"
    backgroundColor="#464343"
    x="32"
    y="33"
    width="45"
    height="60"
    cornerRadius="8"
    borderStyle="solid"
    borderThickness="0"
    click="canvas1_clickHandler(event)"
/>
```

when it is enabled corners are cut
but when canvas is disabled the blured area is with shark corners outside of cut corners.
is it possible to cut the blur as well?

additional info app background is black - with white background blur is not visible because blur color is white as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a `Container` class like `Canvas` is disabled, a rectangle is drawn on top of the container object. As you've noticed, this rectangle doesn't respect the `cornerRadius` style of the container.  To correct this, you can make a custom `Canvas` class that will honor the corner radius (see below).

Some other options are to fiddle with the `disabledBackgroundColor` and `disabledOverlayAlpha` styles, to set a color and alpha so the effect of this problem is less noticeable.

Here's a `CustomCanvas` class that overrides the behavior in the `Container` class and draws it's a rounded rectangle instead of a regular one. The code below is a copy and paste from the original method, w/a slight modification to draw the rounded rectangle.

```
package
{
    import mx.containers.Canvas;
    import mx.core.EdgeMetrics;
    import mx.core.mx_internal;

    use namespace mx_internal;

    public class CustomCanvas extends Canvas
    {
        public function CustomCanvas()
        {
            super();
        }

        override public function validateDisplayList():void
        {
            super.validateDisplayList();
            if (blocker)
            {
                var vm:EdgeMetrics = viewMetrics;

                var bgColor:Object = enabled ?
                    null :
                    getStyle("backgroundDisabledColor");
                if (bgColor === null || isNaN(Number(bgColor)))
                    bgColor = getStyle("backgroundColor");

                if (bgColor === null || isNaN(Number(bgColor)))
                    bgColor = 0xFFFFFF;

                var blockerAlpha:Number = getStyle("disabledOverlayAlpha");

                if (isNaN(blockerAlpha))
                    blockerAlpha = 0.6;

                blocker.x = vm.left;
                blocker.y = vm.top;

                var widthToBlock:Number = unscaledWidth - (vm.left + vm.right);
                var heightToBlock:Number = unscaledHeight - (vm.top + vm.bottom);

                blocker.graphics.clear();
                blocker.graphics.beginFill(uint(bgColor), blockerAlpha);
                // multiply *2 because that's what Container::fillOverlay() does                
                var radius:Number = getStyle("cornerRadius")*2;
                blocker.graphics.drawRoundRect(0,0,widthToBlock, heightToBlock, radius, radius);
                blocker.graphics.endFill();

                // Blocker must be in front of everything
                rawChildren.setChildIndex(blocker, rawChildren.numChildren - 1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```